Bulk insert into SQL Server from python
I have a FastAPI endpoint in python that needs to insert a few thousand rows into a SQL Server table. I have the data in a pandas dataframe and currently I'm looping over the dataframe and inserting them individually. Is there a way to do a bulk insert as this process is timing out the endpoint as it takes too long. I can't use SQLalchemy as the FastAPI script is on an Azure server and SQLalchemy crashes the server.
I have tried SQLalchemy but the library crashes the Azure server the FastAPI script is on.
for _,row in new_df.iterrows():
    cursor.execute(f"""
    insert into ras_import_temp(account_no,amount,[description],eff_date,reference)
    values (?,?,?,?,?)
    """,row.to_list())
cursor.commit()


Perhaps this answer might help.

In pypyodbc, you can use the executemany method instead of looping over your data and calling execute, although it probably won't offer a huge performance boost.
cursor.executemany(f"""
insert into ras_import_temp(account_no,amount,[description],eff_date,reference)
values (?,?,?,?,?)
""", [row.to_list() for _,row in new_df.iterrows()])


I'm using pyodbc, would that make a difference?

@KrokeWaan slightly - see my edited answer

Oh sorry I see I'm using pypyodbc instead of pyodbc as pyodbc also crashes the Azure server. Will it still be possible in the same way?
